# Editing multiple RHEL fstab files

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have to edit multiple /etc/fstab files...about 28 servers
The current line that needs to be

`/dev/vdb        /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0       2`

It has to be

`/dev/vdb        /mnt    ext4  defaults  1  1`

How can I do that with sed or any other suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Used the command -

`find /etc/fstab -print|xargs sed -i '15s/0/1/;14s/2/1/;s/auto/ext4/;s/defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig/default/'` to replace the required fields
and pushed it to the servers through fabric

Thanks